# Conversion from tf.gradients() to tf.GradientTape() returns None

Tags: python, tensorflow, migration, tensorflow2.x, tensorflow1.15

I'm migrating some TF1 code to TF2. For full code, you may check [here](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/acer/acer.py) lines [155-176]. There is a line in TF1 that gets gradients given a loss (float value) and a (m, n) tensor

**Edit:** the problem persists

**Note:** the TF2 code should be compatible and should work inside a `tf.function`

```
g = tf.gradients(-loss, f)  # loss being a float and f being a (m, n) tensor
k = -f_pol / (f + eps)  # f_pol another (m, n) tensor and eps a float
k_dot_g = tf.reduce_sum(k * g, axis=-1)
adj = tf.maximum(
    0.0,
    (tf.reduce_sum(k * g, axis=-1) - delta)
    / (tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(k), axis=-1) + eps),
)
g = g - tf.reshape(adj, [nenvs * nsteps, 1]) * k
grads_f = -g / (nenvs * nsteps)
grads_policy = tf.gradients(f, params, grads_f)  # params being the model parameters
```

In TF2 code I'm trying:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    f = calculate_f()
    f_pol = calculate_f_pol()
    others = do_further_calculations()
    loss = calculate_loss()
g = tape.gradient(-loss, f)
```

However I keep getting `g = [None]` whether I use `tape.watch(f)` or create a `tf.Variable` with the value of `f` or even use `tf.gradients()` inside a `tf.function` because otherwise, it will complain.

Comment: `-loss` is an operation to a tensor, it should be within the tape context in order to be tracked for backpropagation. Try `loss = -calculate_loss()` and then `g = tape.gradient(loss, f)`, or if you prefer `loss = calculate_loss(); nloss = -loss` and then `g = tape.gradient(nloss, f)`.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example with some random data? :)

Comment: @Roelant I already fixed the error and I suspect that some aspect of the loss calculation was happening outside `tf.GradientTape` context which triggered the error.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible to be one of below cases

1. Difine `tf.Variable` inside a function decorated by `@tf.funtion` ?
2. Some variable are numpy.array instead of tf.Tensor
3. You alter some outside variable(i.e. global variable ) inside the decorated function.

Comment: Defining `tf.Variable` inside a `tf.function` usually raises an error. I was able to get rid of the issue by calling the model on the input twice (which does not make much sense). It may be `2.` or `3`. and very likely `3.` It's a very subtle issue as this is like like the 10th time re-writing the code from scratch and I still don't know what's wrong.